# postman not passing more than 2 parameters to .net core api

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-apicontroller

I've a post request like below
[image]

if i send the request in coding side i'm getting value only for the username & password
i'm not getting the DistrictUuid value to api.. please check the below image and let me know if there is any solution for it

[image]

Comment: `DistricUuid" is "int" in C#, but passing as "string" from postman

Comment: @ArulKumar i've updated the 1st image . for int value also i'm getting same problem

Comment: Please ensure there is no typo in the variable `DistrictUuid`, i.e., `t` is missing before `Uuid`

Comment: yes but it's same for the 2 places

Comment: Could you share more details about your `UserRegistrationModel` and your .net core version？ I tried to reproduce the issue in my side, but failed, it works well.

Comment: One more thing, pls ensure there is no typo in your code, and you also can try to add `ApplicationId` in postman for test.

Comment: Use this value in your `raw` data in Body of Postman
      "DistricUuic": 123

Comment: it's .net 6 and yes  Used this value in raw data in Body of Postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the request object in .net end point like this

```
 public class AuthenticateModel
    {
        public string Username;
        public string Password;
        public string DistrictId;
        public string ApplicationId;
     
    }
```

[image]

then sent the post request like this way
with all small case

[image]